# Where to get free math libraries for C/C++

Tags: c++, matlab

Are there free C/C++ libraries taht do the types of functions that matlab does - something complicated i mean, like discrete laplacian, etc? Is the best option to create some kind of interface in matlab and build my own library?

Thanks

Comment: discrete Laplacian is complicated ? I think getting the matrix inversion right is a much more complicated thing to do in C++. There are good libraries in C++, but you'll have to work out most of the things Matlab is so convenient to work with yourself. Please detail your requirements a bit more.

Comment: By complicated I meant having extra steps involved other than doing an inversion, MM, etc.

Comment: In other words, passing a matrix to DEL2 gives me the answer in all one step in matlab

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Boost.Math?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/html/index.html

If you are on windows, there is a very easy to use installer by BoostPro:
http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: `boost::math` emphasizes correctness of IEEE semantics and complexity of use, not simplicity (nor efficiency). This is definitely something I **would not** recommend to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that was a matlab clone but free, you could use Octave http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

I haven't used it in a C++ program, but it apparently has a C++ API:

http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do there are various packages available.

### Arbitrary Precision

- mostly integers: [GMP](http://www.gmplib.org/), [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) (similar codebases, MPIR has VC builds)
- floats: [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/)
- complex: [MPC](http://www.multiprecision.org/)

### Specialist:

- Number Theory: [Flint](http://www.flintlib.org/)
- Linear Algebra: [Boost Numeric uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)
- PDEs: [libMesh](http://libmesh.sourceforge.net/)
- Computational Fluid Dynamics: [OpenFoam](http://www.openfoam.com/)
- Graph Theory: [Boost Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/graph/)

### General:

- [TNT](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/) (was [LAPACK++](http://math.nist.gov/lapack++/) (TNT=do everything, LAPACK++=Linear Alg.)
- [SciMath (Commercial)](http://www.scimath.com/)
- [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)

and that's just a few. I haven't repeated ones others have listed like `libpari`.

Just in case you're wondering, Maple, Mathematica, Matlab etc all use the GNU MP for their arbitrary precision calculations.

Answer (score 1):

PARI could be a good choice, although I am not familiar with using it:

[Official Site for PARI](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)

PARI is a C library, and if you want an independent software, they have PARI-GP there.

Below is the description of PARI on the website above:

> PARI/GP is a widely used computer
>   algebra system designed for fast
>   computations in number theory
>   (factorizations, algebraic number
>   theory, elliptic curves...), but also
>   contains a large number of other
>   useful functions to compute with
>   mathematical entities such as
>   matrices, polynomials, power series,
>   algebraic numbers etc., and a lot of
>   transcendental functions. PARI is also
>   available as a C library to allow for
>   faster computations.

Hope this could be useful!

P.S. It is said that Octave functions could be called from C++, and that could be an excellent substitution for MATLAB.

Comment: @Alexandre C. The website of PARI says it can work with "mathematical entities such as matrices, polynomials, power series, algebraic numbers etc., and a lot of transcendental functions". I do not know what that actually means or if it could help, since I mainly use MATLAB for computing purposes. I apologize if I caused confusion, but I still wonder what PARI could do and what it cannot. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: It can do symbolic computation on matrices, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) for simplifying your handling of matrices. Then for solving PDEs you'll have to do the job yourself, ie. construct explicitly your Laplacian matrix, and solve it the way you want.

There is Intel MKL too (not free though) which adds some value: iterative solvers (GMRES, BCG) and some black-boxes for solving the Laplacian / Poisson equation on simple domains (cubes and spheres).

Answer (score 1):

I use OpenCV for a lot of image processing and matrix manipulation, which is generally what I use matlab for.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

May be overkill depending on what kind of math your trying to do, but it's great for computer vision.

Answer (score 1):

The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) is a free numerical library for C and C++ programmers.

With the [Coder toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-coder/) (requires MATLAB R2011a), you can also turn your MATLAB code into C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

you can use octave runtime:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave#C.2B.2B_Integration