# C++ library that imitates matlab's functionality

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm wondering if there any c/c++ libraries out there that imitate the functuonality that matlab offers (neglecting all the toolboxes of course) and if so, how they compare to matlab in both simplicity and speed?

Comment: Take a look at here for some libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723328/where-to-get-free-math-libraries-for-c-c/5723411#5723411

Comment: [NT2](http://nt2.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standard linear algebra, [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) essentially has *"ease of use"* a la Matlab as a stated goal. Quoting from the main page:

> - Armadillo is an open-source C++
>     linear algebra library (matrix maths)
>     aiming towards a good balance between
>     speed and ease of use. Integer,
>     floating point and complex numbers are
>     supported, as well as a subset of
>     trigonometric and statistics
>     functions. Various matrix
>     decompositions are provided through
>     optional integration with LAPACK, or
>     one of its high performance drop-in
>     replacements (such as MKL or ACML).
> - This library is useful if C++ has
>     been decided as the language of choice
>     (due to speed and/or integration
>     capabilities), rather than another
>     language like Matlab ® or Octave. It
>     is distributed under a license that is
>     useful in both open-source and
>     commercial contexts.

It is a pretty decent C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that provide basic linear algebra (BLAS) implementations. However, I think you'll find matlab has so many convient functions that get use very frequently you will have a hard time porting your matlab over to c+++ even with a nice BLAS library.

Check out GNU Octave. It provides a runtime that closely mirrors matlab. It also allows you to embed and extend the runtime within your C++ application

Comment: I have worked a bit with blas, but as you say its not really comparable, matlab is just so much easier to work with. What kind os speeds do you get when integrating octave into C++?

Comment: I didn't notice any significant overhead in calling into the octave code. The running time of our m code within the standard octave interpreter environment was the same as when we integrated the interpreter to be called by c++.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned anything regarding the licensing of the library, you may want to look at this:

http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/